# Representing relations as features for supervised learning tasks

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to use relations between objects for a supervised learning task.
For eg, given a text like "Cats eat fish" , I would like to use the relation Cats-eat-fish as a feature for learning task (namely identifying the sense of a word). I thus would like to represent this relation numerically so that I could use it as a feature for a learning a model. Any suggestions on how I could accomplish that. I was thinking of hashing it to an integer but that could pose challenges like two relations semantically the same could have 2 very different hash values. I ideally would like 2 similar relations (for eg lives and resides) to hash to the same value. I guess I would also need to figure out if I could canonicalize relations before hashing.

Other approaches perhaps not using numerical features would also be useful. I am also wondering if there are graph based approaches to this problem.

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Comment: I just ended up using a graph based approach where a relation is an edge between 2 entities.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making (very large numbers) of binary features for all possible relation types, and then possibly running some form of dimensionality reduction on the resulting (very sparse) feature space.

Another way to do this, which would reduce sparsity, would be to replace the bare words with entity types, for example [animal] eats [animal], or even [animate] eats [animate], and then use binary features in this space. You want to avoid mapping to numerical values on a single dimension because you'll impose spurious ordinal relations between features if you do.

Answer (score 0):

How about representing verbs by features that would express typical words preceding the verb (usually subject) and typical words following the verb (usually object). Say you can take 500 most frequent words (or even better most discriminating words), then each verb would be represented as a 1000-dimensional vector. Each feature in the vector can be either binary (is there the word with frequency above certain threshold or not), or pure count, or probably best as logarithm. Then you can run PCA to reduce the vector to some smaller dimension.

The approach above is probabilistic which might be good or bad depending on what you want. IF you want to do it precisely with a lot of manual input, then look at situation semantics.